# Android setText() is crashing

Tags: android, user-interface, view, textview

I'm making a custom ArrayAdapter for my music player app, and when I try to set the text of a View, my app crashes. I am aware from looking on the forums that you cannot access UI elements from the background thread or you must setContentView() before you try something like this, however my situation is a little different. Any ideas?

MusicAdapter.class

```
Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
Song data[] = null;

private Handler threadHandler = new Handler();

public MusicAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Song[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    SongHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new SongHolder();
        holder.txtTitle =  (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.songName);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (SongHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Song song = data[position];

    holder.txtTitle.setText(song.title); //This line crashes
    return row;
}


static class SongHolder{
    TextView txtTitle;
}
```

}

My error message:
01-11 21:34:38.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32319): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 21:34:38.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32319): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 21:34:38.226: E/AndroidRuntime(32319):    at com.example.audity.MusicAdapter$SongHolder.(MusicAdapter.java:51)

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Updated the question with the error

Comment: given its a null pointer exception then either holder or txtTitle or song is a null. You should try isolating each of these to find which it is

Comment: If anything the TextView is null, but as you can see I define the value of holder.txtTitle earlier in the method. And I hard coded the new text and it still throws a NullPointer. This is some of that weird android shit

Comment: Its odd to me cause I know the TextArea is null, but it has no reason to be

Comment: static class SongHolder{
        TextView txtTitle;
    }

Comment: The first line in an inner class

Comment: @NickPetryna Have you tried to rebuild the application from scratch? `Project -> Clean`

Comment: No, I havent. Its a pretty big app for my Software engineering course due in a day so im not really sure if thats an option

Comment: I may just have to use a basic ArrayAdapter for now

Comment: can you post your xml as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as i see your code your crash maybe for :

```
if(row == null){
    holder.txtTitle =  (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.songName);
}else{
    //txtTitle  not initialized here
}
holder.txtTitle.setText(song.title);
```

txtTitle not initialized on else block and use on below of it

hope to be useful :)